# Display text and direct via hyperlink on d3 Map

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, geojson

I have an interactive d3 map running (http://atlas.niu.edu/afd/) that is based on a topojson file. The structure of the topojson is as follows:

[image: attributes]

I'd like to display the CWA and City on mouseover and redirect to a specific URL for each feature geometry. I can hard code in each URL or store them in a separate csv file if necessary. Any examples would be very helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The url redirection:**

The same  way you listen to `.on('mouseover'`, you can listen to `.on("click"` to perform an action when the user clicks on a state:

```
.on("click", function(d) {
  window.open("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + d.properties.State, "_blank");
})
```

**The mouseover tooltip displaying the CWA and the City:**

You can add a `svg:title` to your states nodes which will display the given text when a state is hovered (following the mouseover/click definitions):

```
.append("svg:title")
.text( function(d) { return d.properties.CWA + " - " + d.properties.City; });
```

---

Here is a [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/IUfNDmuWktQBhSjqe49f?p=preview)

Comment: Y'all are awesome. Almost there. My issue here is that the hyperlink is not something stored in the topojson. For example, KLOT (Chicago) would direct here: http://kamala.cod.edu/il/latest.fxus63.KLOT.html   while Cleveland would direct here: http://kamala.cod.edu/oh/latest.fxus61.KCLE.html

Would it be best to store links as a field record in the topojson (I can probably accomplish that) or store them in a seperate .csv (and if so what would that look like?

Comment: Actually, I found a different/better source. 

https://forecast.weather.gov/product.php?site=NWS&issuedby=DVN&product=AFD&format=txt&version=1&glossary=1&highlight=off

Thus, all I need to do is figure out how to substitute issuedby = _____ for each of the CWA variables. I'll see if I can get it!

Answer (score 3):

@Xavier's answer is one good approach to get what you're looking for. Although, here's another approach to do the same.

**Apparently I found some time to use the data from your site and use it in a plunkr**

Here's a plunkr for the same: http://plnkr.co/edit/rlC38fQRU4oF3QslYUbz?p=preview

For the tooltips, I'm just adding a simple `div` tooltip fetching the `CW` and `City` properties.

```
// Define the div for the tooltip
var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
 .attr("class", "tooltip")              
 .style("opacity", 0);
```

On mouseover:

```
.on('mouseover',function(d) {
   d3.select(this).classed("selected",true);
   div.html('CWA: ' + d.properties.CWA + "<br/>"  + 'City: ' + d.properties.City)   
    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px").style("opacity", .9);
```

And for the links (url), I'm wrapping the `paths` within an **anchor** tag with `target=_blank" (open in a new window) which defaults to [d3JS](https://d3js.org) if no`url` is found in the properties.

Relevant code:

```
svg.selectAll(".nwscwa")
.data(cwas)
.enter().append('a')
.attr('xlink:href', function(d) {
  return d.properties.link || "https://d3js.org";
}).attr('target', '_blank')
```

Hope this approach helps and let me know if the plunkr doesn't work for you.

Comment: Well I had the map functioning locally but couldn't make it work within the stack overflow dedicated code snippet. I'm curious on which setting you used to have it functioning with plunker.

Comment: I tried fetching the data (a couple of rows) and posting it into a new file in plunkr but then just passing of the URL (without being https) `.defer(d3.json,"http://atlas.niu.edu/afd/beddd.json")` worked. So just used it.

Comment: Y'all are awesome. Almost there. My issue here is that the hyperlink is not something stored in the topojson. For example, KLOT (Chicago) would direct here: http://kamala.cod.edu/il/latest.fxus63.KLOT.html   while Cleveland would direct here: http://kamala.cod.edu/oh/latest.fxus61.KCLE.html

Would it be best to store links as a field record in the topojson (I can probably accomplish that) or store them in a seperate .csv (and if so what would that look like?

Comment: Actually, I found a different/better source. 

https://forecast.weather.gov/product.php?site=NWS&issuedby=DVN&product=AFD&format=txt&version=1&glossary=1&highlight=off

Thus, all I need to do is figure out how to substitute issuedby = _____ for each of the CWA variables. I'll see if I can get it!

Comment: Glad we could help. That should be pretty easy to just substitute the values. If not, let me know, I'll help you out.